# Proguard is not obfuscating classes in project correctly

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to using Proguard to obfuscate classes in my project. After building project, I decompile the Apk and check whether the classes are obfuscated successfully. However, I find out that almost all the classes are not renamed except some library classes. Here is the screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8OVk.png)

The following is a part of my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        sign {
            storeFile file(KEYSTORE_FILE)
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias KEYSTORE_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.findata.gcool"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.1.7"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sign
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

And proguard-rules.pro:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/doris_yang/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keep class com.findata.gcool.bean.** { *; }
-keep class com.findata.gcool.bean.json.** { *; }
-keep class com.findata.gcool.http.** { *; }
-keep class com.findata.gcool.widget.custom_view.** { *; }

# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

##---------- Gson from official ----------
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

#---------- Retrofit 2.X from official ----------
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

#---------- EventBus------------------
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends    org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}

#-----------Crahslytics-----------
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

#---------- Other  ----------
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.roughike.bottombar.**
```

Even if I remove all the rules except -dontwarn rules(can't build without them), the result is still the same. It seems that Proguard is working but not working correctly on my project files. I have no idea why it happens :(

Thanks for reviewing my problem!